# Make values ​converge to the minimum value in a data series

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code to generate an array:

```
import numpy as np

dimension = 2
tamaño = 8
decrement = 0.9
matriz = np.asarray([np.random.random(dimension) for _ in range(tamaño)])
print(matriz)
minimo = np.amin(matriz[:,0])

for _ in range(100):
  #Es aqui donde graduaremos exponencialmente los valores
```

I have a matrix of size 2x8. I then identify the minimum value in the column "[0]", in order to create a loop of N iterations to make that in each of them the other elements converge to that minimum value But The issue is that for them to converge in a "gradual" way, the value of the decrease variable would not have to be the same for everyone and that is where my question comes from. What would I have to do to modify the value of the variable in each iteration " Decrement"" To such an extent that when the last iterations are reached there is a minimum standard deviation

Psdt: I found this on SO I hope it helps

[numpy / scipy: Making one series converge towards another after a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141798/numpy-scipy-making-one-series-converge-towards-another-after-a-period-of-time)

## Example:

```
[[0.90853515 0.62336012]
 [0.01582124 0.92943723]
 [0.69089692 0.99732285]
 [0.17234051 0.13713575]
 [0.93259546 0.69681816]
 [0.06600017 0.75546305]
 [0.75387619 0.92302454]
 [0.71152476 0.12427096]]
```

As we can observe the minimum value of that matrix would be:

`0.015821242846556283`

What we have to proceed to do is auto-adjust the other values ​​in each iteration minimally as long as they converge to the minimum at the end of the column in which we are adjusting. It could look like this:

```
 [0.01592127
  0.01589542
  0.015826342
  0.01534542
  0.01582452
  0.015834542
  0.0158456
  0.01582435]
```

Nota:
They don't have to perfectly converge after their first 2 or 3 digits are the same, the others don't matter so much I accept several solutions to this problem They don't have to perfectly converge after their first 2 or 3 digits are the same, the others don't matter so much I accept several solutions to this issue

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite some of this for reproducibility:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(3)

matriz = rng.random((8, 2))
minimo = np.min(matriz[:,0])
```

Here the `matriz` will look like the following, and `minimo` will be bound to `0.08564916714362436`:

```
[[0.08564917 0.23681051]
 [0.80127447 0.58216204]
 [0.09412864 0.43312694]
 [0.4790513  0.15973891]
 [0.73457715 0.11367202]
 [0.39122819 0.51674018]
 [0.43062802 0.58679857]
 [0.73783779 0.95626725]]
```

### Linear Case

If the goal is to find an array where the final value decreases until the `minimo` value, the simplest solution might be:

```py
SCALE = 0.001
sequence = (np.arange(matriz.shape[0])[::-1] * SCALE) + minimo
```

which results in:

```py
[0.09264917 0.09164917 0.09064917 0.08964917 0.08864917 0.08764917
 0.08664917 0.08564917]
```

### Exponential Case

If the goal is instead to decrease the values such that they follow an exponential, another parameter can be added:

```py
LIN_SCALE = 0.1
EXP_SCALE = 2.0

sequence = ((np.arange(matriz.shape[0])[::-1] * LIN_SCALE) ** EXP_SCALE) + minimo
```

Which results in:

```py
[0.57564917 0.44564917 0.33564917 0.24564917 0.17564917 0.12564917
 0.09564917 0.08564917]
```

### Random Noise

One final point mentioned in the question is the presence of noise: such that it may not matter *exactly* how much the sequence decreases by, so long as the final number converges to the minimum value.

We could represent this by sampling from a normal distribution with `loc=0.0`, `scale=SIG_SCALE`:

```py
LIN_SCALE = 0.1
EXP_SCALE = 2.0
SIG_SCALE = 0.1

noise = rng.normal(scale=SIG_SCALE, size=matriz.shape[0])
noise[-1] = 0.0
ran_seq = (
    ((np.arange(matriz.shape[0])[::-1] * LIN_SCALE) ** EXP_SCALE) + noise
) + minimo
```

Which looks something like this:

```py
[0.62384371 0.42179381 0.43142504 0.22566895 0.17807512 0.28023125
 0.15015972 0.08564917]
```

### Generalization

The final version can be generalized. For example: the linear decreasing case is produced when the exponential parameter is `1.0` and the random scale parameter is `0.0`: which corresponds to raising the vector to the first power (no effect) and sampling from a 0-variance distribution (no effect):

[image: Comparison of the three decreasing functions.]

---

**Further Explanation**: The idea here is to guarantee convergence by linearly decreasing in each step. Reversing the result of `np.arange` gives an array that decreases from `7` down to `0`. Multiplying this by our `SCALE` parameter simply makes these values smaller. Finally, adding the `minimo` value to this array makes it so every rescaled value is proportional to the smallest value (and since the final value from the `arange` call is `0`, `0 + minimo = minimo`).

```
1. [7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0] # np.arange(8)[::-1]
2. [0.007 0.006 0.005 0.004 0.003 0.002 0.001 0.   ]
3. [0.092 0.091 ... 0.0856]
```

This should guarantee a strictly monotonic decreasing sequence, and only requires setting the `LIN_SCALE` or `EXP_SCALE` parameters.

Comment: What type of random numbers do you recommend I use?

Comment: Can you refine what you mean by "*What type of random numbers do you recommend*"? Currently the only source of randomness is from the calls that produce `matriz`. There is no randomness in the decreasing sequence, but there could be.

Comment: how could there be randomness in the decreasing sequence? What are you talking about? Could you adjust your answer to that statement? thanks good answer

Comment: I mean that "There are" different random number generators, which of them should I use? Or is it something inconsequential?

Comment: I added an example showing the effect of sampling from a normal distribution with tuneable variance. Using different random number generators probably won't make a difference: I think the default generator used in numpy is based on the MersenneTwister, which is pretty standard and used across quite a few languages. You might experiment with sampling from different distributions (e.g. poisson, logistic) depending on your needs. Poisson is good for modeling count data and produces integers, for example.

Comment: **Correction**: Numpy uses the PCG64 as of 1.17: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/pcg64.html